# How to fetch the particular part from the string if there are lot of strings in a generic way

Tags: java, string

```
http://m.facebook.com/messages/1245/abc
http://m.facebook.com/messages/12/
http://m.facebook.com/messages/5/
http://m.facebook.com/messages/particular_String/abcd/Trigma
```

So these are the urls and i would like to fetch the 1245 from first url 12 from second 5 from third and particular_string from fourth.how can i do this?

Comment: Probably substring ?

Answer (score 1):

Use [String.split](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to get all the substrings in the string that are between the '/' delimeter as an array, like so

```
myString.split("/")
```

from `"http://m.facebook.com/messages/1245/abc"`
you will get an array of

```
http:

m.facebook.com
messages
1245
abc
```

then get the one which is 1245

Answer (score 1):

Well if all urls have the same base, namely-

> http://m.facebook.com/messages/

I would replace that like

**urlString = urlString.replace ("http://m.facebook.com/messages/","");**

Then tokenize the remaining portion to get the first part.

StringTokenizer tokenizedString = new StringTokenizer(urlString, "/");

String requiredString = tokenizedString.nextToken();

Answer (score 0):

Probably you may use `String.contains()` method to check if the 1245 exist int the url -

```
String extractString(String url, String key){

   if( url.contains(key) ){
      return key;
   }

  return null;
}
```

Now for `url1` call `extractString()` method  like this -

```
String url1 = "http://m.facebook.com/messages/1245/abc"
String key = "1234";
String returnValue = extractString(url1, key);
```